# Call to a member function diffForHumans() on null

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, php-carbon

i am getting outputs of my posts in the system but i am getting this errror Call to a member function diffForHumans() on null... Can u please help me? Thanks...

Article model is that:

```
protected $fillable=[
        'user_id','content','live','post_on'
    ];

public function setLiveAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['live']=(boolean)($value);
}
```

And the articlescontroller is that

```
public function index()
{
    $articles = Article::all();
    return view('articles.index', compact('articles'));
}

public function create()
{   
    return view('articles.create');
}

public function store(Request $request)
{


    Article::create($request->all());

}

public function show()
{   

}

public function update()
{   

}

public function destroy()
{   

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is for sure not here. You probably try to run `diffForHumans()` in your view for example like this:

```
$user->post_on->diffForHumans()
```

but `post_on` is set to `null` instead of date.

So you should verify where exactly you run this method, set this column as date and in your view add something like this:

```
Posted: {{ $date ? $date->diffForHumans: '-' }}
```